# Java - ClassFileTransformer.transform(...) concurrect invocation for the same classLoader&className pair

Tags: java, concurrency, transform, instrumentation

J2SE 5.0 specification for method ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassLoader classLoader, String className, Class classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) tells:

> transformer will be called for every new class definition and every
>   class redefinition. The request for a new class definition is made
>   with ClassLoader.defineClass. The request for a class redefinition is
>   made with Instrumentation.redefineClasses or its native equivalents.
>   The transformer is called during the processing of the request, before
>   the class file bytes have been verified or applied.

Using this information I can't say if it's possible for method ClassFileTransformer.transform to be called concurrently for the same runtime class (classLoader&className). I understand that method Instrumentation.redefineClasses can be called concurrently for the same class, but this doesn't mean that such invocation can lead to  concurrent invocation of ClassFileTransformer.transform for the same class. Is there some way to clarify my incomprehension?

It's important in my case, because I use Javassist for transformation and the same instance of CtClass can be used from concurrently running methods ClassFileTransformer.transform. Currently I do all work with CtClass instance within synchronized(ctClass) block, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to invoke method `Instrumentation.redefineClasses` concurrently for the same class and checked if my class file transformer `transform` method was invoked concurrently. And the answer is yes, `ClassFileTransformer.transform` methods can be invoked by JVM  for the same class concurrently.